# getMFAResponseForSite stop working

Tags: yodlee

Today suddenly all my integration tests started to fail because after 15 attempts with delay 5 sec to call getMFAResponseForSite I've received following response

```
{ "isMessageAvailable": false, "timeOutTime": 0, "itemId": 0,
  "memSiteAccId": 10040168, "retry": true }
```

Test log:

```
[Site]: siteId: '12287' name: 'ANZ (New Zealand)' url: 'http://www.anz.co.nz/'
SiteAccId: 10040168
MfaRefresh is started...
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 0
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 1
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 2
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 3
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 4
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 5
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 6
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 7
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 8
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 9
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 10
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 11
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 12
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 13
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 14
[GetMfaResponse] errorCode: , isMessageAvailable: False, retryNo: 15
```

It looks to me yodlee doesn't call bank sites because if I put invalid credentials to login form it doesn't change test results. In spite of this I can access bank account using online banking site.

Is it related to my test account or there is some problem on yodlee test server side?

Comment: After few hour this problem gone. I wonder does such issue related to test account only or it can be occurred on production environment.

Comment: Ideally this should not happen in any environment. But there was maintenance done on the test portal and hence the service might have been affected by that. In production clients are reported in advance about the activity.